# How to preload globally some records from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, singleton, persistence

On example I have a site settings or list of user permissions. I want to ensure that only one call to these data would be done (kind of singletonish logic here).

I think this could be possible to use a Service Container that loads the data in a middleware and use it like

```
$permissions = app('permissions'); // Collection
```

or

```
$systemSettings = app('systemSettings');
```

Which could be accessible in unit tests and any other place of the Laravel app.

Aside question is if that would work better with redis maybe? Smaller overhead on opened connections, faster access, data that rarely changes and are pretty much key-value

Comment: What I did with permissions - created helper that you can pass 'key' of permission and get `true|false`. Permissions for user are stored in cache. If cache key can't be found my helper reads permissions from DB and stores in cache before returning

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I want to go more wide. Instead of asking the cache for specific permission I want to load all user permissions once and query them from memory. The specific user permissions would be reloaded with every request in most efficient manner without touching files on disk (this is at best decent if there are multiple php fpms running). While your solution is good it requires a cache invalidation and some complexity around that while I prefer to query the materialized view from database and store it in memory.

Comment: You can make is so that not passing permission key returns array / collection as it is anyways reads from cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define singleton on **AppServiceProvider** in **boot** function :

```
      $this->app->singleton( 'systemSettings', function () {
           return Settings::get();
        } );
```

then use it by calling :

```
$systemSettings = app('systemSettings');
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!